# TensorFlow: restore weights more than one time in a graph

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a model in two steps:

**Step 1**, train Model1, trainable layer is `conv1`:

```
input1  conv1  output1
```

**Step 2**, train Model2 with weights of `conv1` in Model1 (Model1 has been trained). Here, trainable layer is only `fc1` (suppose we have the weights of `fc2`):

```
input2  fc1  conv1  output2  loss
        fc2  conv1  output3
```

Two `conv1` in Model2 are in different scopes and have different input (`fc1` and `fc1`), but there is only one name I can define when saving `conv1` in Model1.

How can I restore weights of `conv1` more than one time (it is used two times as shown above) into graph of Model2?

Comment: Are the two `conv1` instances in the second example the same Python object (in particular, do they use the same variables?). If so, you'll only need to restore the weights once, i.e., variable restoration should just work.

Comment: @AkshayAgrawal two `conv1` have same weights, thus I think it's ok to let them be the same object. If restore the weight once, how can I connect two different input (`fc1` and `fc2`) to it?